# Windows 7 Phone Cannot figure out how to get rid of white bounding rec on Buttons

Tags: windows-phone-7

I created 2 Image buttons.  Right now there is a white rectangle drawn around the image.  Is there a way to turn this off, or change the color?  I looked in the properties pan, but could not find any property for border.
Here isd the xml code

```
<Button  Height="140" Name="button1" Width="332" Padding="0"  >
   <Image Source="/BigBiz;component/resource/bannerleft.png" ManipulationStarted="button1_Click" Width="319" Height="113"></Image>
</Button>

<Button  Height="140" Name="button2" Width="332" Padding="0"  >
    <Image Source="/BigBiz;component/resource/bannerleft.png" ManipulationStarted="button2_Click" Width="327" Height="113"></Image>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try following code. i hope it's solved your problem.

```
<Button Height="140" Name="button2" Width="332" click="button2_Click" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0">
                <Button.OpacityMask>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/BigBiz;component/resource/bannerleft.png" />
                </Button.OpacityMask>
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/BigBiz;component/resource/bannerleft.png" />
                </Button.Background>           
</Button>
```